Invalid route action: [Pterodactyl\Http\Controllers\Admin\Nodes\SystemInformationController]
I am lost and I dont get this can someone help me please
Well I was trying to install a theme for my hosting, and then I clicked replaced and it broke alot but I fixed some errors but now im stuck on this error, I tried looking for other documents and I tried contacting my hosting but they did not wanna help me. So Im seeking the help as I am lost and cant figure it out.
